# Convolving two arrays in python without for loops

Tags: python

I have two arrays(`arr_1,arr_2`), and need to generate an output(`arr_out`) as follows:

```
arr_1 = [21, 28, 36, 29, 40]
arr_2 = [0, 225, 225, 0, 225]

arr_out = [-1, 28, 36, -1, 40]
```

The outputarr_out should have -1 at an index if the product of the elements in arr_1 and arr_2 at that index is 0. Otherwise, the value from arr_1 should be in the output array.

I have implemented a solution using a for loop:

```
 arr_out = [0] * 5

 for index, value in enumerate(arr_1):
    if (value * arr_2[index]) == 0:
        arr_out[index] = -1
    else:
        arr_out[index] = value
```

Is it possible to achieve this without using a for loop?

Comment: Sorry about the rollbacks, I had overlooked the OP's own later edit. @Moshe : please don't change ambiguous code like that. They call them arrays, their variables have an "arr" prefix, they showed their data without commas like NumPy arrays would, and they asked for solutions without loop. That's a lot of indications that they might actually have NumPy arrays, and it's not ok for us to decide that they have lists instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using list comprehensions along with the zip function:

```py
arr_out = [-1 if (x * y) == 0 else x for x, y in zip(arr_1, arr_2)]
```

This will remove the need for `for` loops as well as `enumerate`. We're using the zip function, which combines two lists element-wise. Then, we use a list comprehension to loop through the combined elements and perform the desired operation.

Comment: Could also check if either `x` or `y` is zero, might be faster for large values.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Would also be shorter: `[y and x or -1 for x, y in zip(arr_1, arr_2)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and convert `list` to `numpy.array` then use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
import numpy as np
arr_1 = [21, 28, 36, 29, 40]
arr_2 = [0, 225, 225, 0, 225]

np_arr_1 = np.array(arr_1)
np_arr_2 = np.array(arr_2)
arr_out = np.where(np_arr_1 * np_arr_2 == 0, -1, np_arr_1)
print(arr_out)
```

Output:

```
[-1 28 36 -1 40]
```